# Can emacs window be "partially" dedicated?

Tags: emacs

I'm using [`dedicated.el`](https://github.com/emacsmirror/dedicated/blob/master/dedicated.el) which is very similar to [`dedicate-windows-manually.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/dedicate-windows-manually.el) to manually mark certain windows as "dedicated" to their buffer and also inelegible for splitting by various commands that open new buffers (grep, compilation, etc.).

But I really only want the second part.

In other words, I want `find-file`, `kill-buffer`, `switch-buffer` and so on to work as if the current window was *not* dedicated. But I want other commands (`grep`, `compile`) to honor the dedicated status and not split that window.

I made a small attempt at this, but it doesn't work properly and seems like a misguided way to go about it, likely missing many cases.

(One of the problems is that the "dedicated" minor mode is associated with a buffer while `set-window-dedicated-p` applies to a *window*; this could be overcome, but I still feel there must be a better way to accomplish what I want...)

```
(defun with-undedicated (f)
  (interactive)
  (let ((was-dedicated (bound-and-true-p dedicated-mode)))
    (progn
      (if was-dedicated (dedicated-mode))
      (command-execute f)
      (if was-dedicated (dedicated-mode)))))

(defun undedicated-find-file ()
  (interactive)
  (with-undedicated 'ido-find-file))

(defun undedicated-kill-buffer ()
  (interactive)
  (with-undedicated 'ido-kill-buffer))

(defun undedicated-switch-buffer ()
  (interactive)
  (with-undedicated 'ido-switch-buffer))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-f") 'undedicated-find-file)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x k") 'undedicated-kill-buffer)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x b") 'undedicated-switch-buffer)
```

**edit**

The following was performed to test Drew's answer:

```
(defun make-weak-dedicated ()
  (interactive)
  (set-window-dedicated-p (selected-window) "weak"))

(defun dedicated-status ()
  (interactive)
  (minibuffer-message "window-dedicated-p: %s" (window-dedicated-p (selected-window))))
```

Making the window "weak"ly dedicated does indeed do what I want: grep and other popup buffers do not replace the buffer in the weakly dedicated window. However, in that weakly dedicated window, `find-file` seems to reset `window-dedicated-p` to `nil` as tested by my `dedicated-status` function, so I still don't have a technique to *prevent* popup buffers from using or splitting a window *and* allowing `find-file` etc. to work as normal within that window.

**clarification**

Sorry for not being clear. Here's what I want to happen:

- I mark a window as [weakly] dedicated (or whatever equivalent may exist)
- I invoke grep, compilation, and so on, and they do not split that window nor replace the buffer in that window (instead splitting some other window that is not marked dedicated)
- Within the weakly dedicated window, I invoke `find-file`, which replaces the buffer in the window *but leaves the window weakly dedicated* to the now changed buffer

It's that last bit that isn't working how I had hoped: after `find-file`, the window is no longer weakly dedicated (`window-dedicated-p` is `nil`). Since the property in question is associated with the window, I find it surprising that changing the buffer affected that window property, but so it is.

Comment: `find-file` replaces the buffer in the current window. I don't know what you mean by allowing it to "work as normal within that window". Try giving a description of the behavior you are looking for - e.g. a recipe: you do this, then this... and you want to see this, then that... result.

Answer (score 2):

See the Elisp manual, node [`Dedicated Windows`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Dedicated-Windows.html). If you use function `set-window-dedicated-p` to give a window a non-`nil` and non-`t` value then function [`set-window-buffer`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Buffers-and-Windows.html) will respect it as a weakly dedicated window. That may be what you are looking for.

Comment: Setting `window-dedicated-p` to a string does seem to work, thanks.  Only problem is after `find-file`, the value reverts back to `nil`.

Comment: Dunno what you mean - give an example (recipe) showing the problem. Perhaps you are saying only that weakly dedicated is not strongly dedicated (?), and that you can therefore visit another buffer (e.g. file) in the same window.

Comment: I've added some example code to my original question.